# INNER JOIN is not updated in the target table in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to make the `money` table `spend` passed to `subtotals` of the `salary` table, also that `savings` from the `save` table pass to subtotale of the salary table.

1.- When you add data in `spent` and / or `savings` for the first time if it works

2 .- When updating or deleting data in the `save` or `money` table does not update in the `salary` table

I only gave an example of one of the tables from where it originally obtained the data since in the other it is the same

- 1.- In this part add a data to spent and it works:

```
router.post('/contador', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    const { spent, description } = req.body;
    const sp = {
        spent,
        description,
        user_id: req.user.id
    };
    console.log(sp);
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO money set ?', [sp]);
    await pool.query('UPDATE salary as sa INNER JOIN money as mo ON sa.user_id = mo.user_id SET sa.subtotals = mo.spent');
    await pool.query('UPDATE salary as sa set sa.totals = sa.subtotals + sa.subtotala');
    await pool.query('UPDATE salary as sa set sa.total = sa.moneywon - sa.totals');
    req.flash('success', 'Gasto agregado');
    res.redirect('/links');
});
```

- 2.- In this part edit a data of spent and do not update in the salary table:

```
router.post('/edit/:id', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { spent, description } = req.body;
    const sp = {
        spent,
        description
    };
    await pool.query('UPDATE money set ? WHERE id = ?', [sp, id]);
    await pool.query('UPDATE salary as sa INNER JOIN money as mo ON sa.user_id = mo.user_id SET sa.subtotals = mo.spent');
    await pool.query('UPDATE salary as sa set sa.totals = sa.subtotals + sa.subtotala');
    await pool.query('UPDATE salary as sa set sa.total = sa.moneywon - sa.totals');
    req.flash('success', 'Actualizado');
    res.redirect('/links');
});
```

I hope that in the salary table I update according to what I have in the money table with the row spent

Unfortunately, I don't get an error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspecting of some locking issues because `async/await` will only work with `Promise`

```
router.post('/edit/:id', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { spent, description } = req.body;
    const sp = {
        spent,
        description
    };
    await Update_First(sp, id);    
    await pool.query('UPDATE salary as sa INNER JOIN money as mo ON sa.user_id = mo.user_id SET sa.subtotals = mo.spent');
    await pool.query('UPDATE salary as sa set sa.totals = sa.subtotals + sa.subtotala');
    await pool.query('UPDATE salary as sa set sa.total = sa.moneywon - sa.totals');
    req.flash('success', 'Actualizado');
    res.redirect('/links');
});
```

**using Promise**

```
var Update_First= function(sp, id){   
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ 
        await pool.query('UPDATE money set ? WHERE id = ?', [sp, id]);
    });
}
```